# A loop within a function that is also in a loop gives an error

Tags: function, loops, maps, jsfiddle

How can i get this function out of the i iteration loop, since jshint gives me an error.

```
 for (i = 0; i < portfolios.length; i++) {
            return function () {
                for (h = 0; h < markers.length; h++) {
                    markers[h].infobox.close();
                }
                markers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
            };
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: The line `})(marker, i));` looks suspect... Also, you're returning inside the loop, so it will only run once (for the value of `i = 0`). I think.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mqrrA/29/ <-- here is the project, if you click jshint you will see the one error [Don't make functions within a loop]. I would ignore the error, however it won't allow other parameters to take effect because of it. Such as starting zoom level. or position of the map. So that is why i must fix it - it is breaking something else.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the issue and I also agree with what @iamnotmaynard mentioned.

Comment: Well, it says "don't make a function within a loop" on jsfiddle. I would ignore this, but if you go to the fiddle and go to line 28 (starting zoom on the map) it doesn't work for any value. But if I take this function in the loop out it does work. However, I need this function for making sure the info boxes close when another one is open - So i need all parameters to work. If I can bring this function out of the i iteration I think the zoom and "center" variable would be restored. if that makes sense....

Comment: At line 28 I see `zoom: 1` (http://jsfiddle.net/mqrrA/29/). In addition, I opened two different popups on the map and I was able to close them using the `x` button. I'm still not understanding the issue.

Comment: change the zoom to anything: 1, 2, 3, 4,.. and you can also change the center(lat, long) to anything [line 25] but these changes will not get passed through. My guess is something to do with this error jsHINT gives out. because if i remove the function in question (like completly delete it) the zoom and center variables will get passed through.The function however controls the popups close and open. So basically right now:I either have the pop up [auto close if new popup is clicked] or I have the zoom and center parameters. Thos are the only two I know are broken when this function is present.

Comment: Alright do this, leave your current jsfiddle as is, fork another version of your current jsfiddle and strip out what you need to strip out so I can see your error then I'll be able to compare the two jsfiddles and hopefully figure out what's going on

Comment: ah i got it:     

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
        return markers;

overrides the zoom and center variables. I thought it had something to do with the function in the loop but it did not :) Still somewhat curious to know why jsfiddle does give this error, but guess I will not worry about it :) Thanks!

Comment: You did all the work, I'm glad you could resolve it :)