# inline css javascript text decoration

Tags: css, text, hyperlink, styles

If I have the following code for an element in line javascript:

```
boxText.style.cssText = "text-decoration: none; border:1px solid black;    margin-top: 8px;    background:black;    color:white;    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    font-size:12px;    padding: .5em 1em;    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;    -moz-border-radius: 3px;    border-radius: 3x;    text-shadow:0 0px #000000;    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0  8px #000;    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;";
```

How can I get the text decoration to be none to work and control the hover, active, visited, link colors as well? Everything works but the text decoration and I don't know how to incorporate the link color styles.

thanks!

Comment: Please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing as it is working fine here.[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/BqbZM/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mqrrA/32/  line 90. When you click on a marker on the map the title is a link - but I don't want it to be underlined and I want to change the link colors. I inputted text-decoration:none into the css element (which is inline with the javascript) but it does not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BqbZM/1/ and no it does not Saurabh. If you make a link to the hellp it becomes underlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `boxText` is a div as its initialized as `var boxText = document.createElement("div");`

To resolve this, you need to assign your styles to the `a` tag instead. So basically you'll change this:

**Method 1**

`boxText.innerHTML = "<a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "'>"`

To something like this

`boxText.innerHTML = "<a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "' style='text-decoration:none; color:red;'>"`

In this demo, you'll notice the `a` tag has no **border** and it's colored **red**

http://jsfiddle.net/vumu6/

**Method 2**

Give the `a` tag, within your `boxText`, a class name something like:

`boxText.innerHTML = "<a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "' class='caption-title-link'>"`

Then you can do whatever you want to the `.caption-title-link` class in the styles. For example

```
.caption-title-link {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:red;
}

.caption-title-link:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.caption-title-link:active {
     color: green;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zqCdt/

Comment: nice thank you :) is there a way to do the hover, active, visited link colors as well?

Comment: now if only someone would fix my loop function problem, haha.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742651/a-loop-within-a-function-that-is-also-in-a-loop-gives-an-error?noredirect=1#comment32885274_21742651

Comment: Sure. Also, not to pressure you or anything but if my answer did help resolve your question, can you please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: geeezz it's like a pressure cooker in here. haha. Of course I can :) Again thanks for your help - saved me a bunch of time.